# AWS monitoring solution for SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

We have more than 100 SQS queues and its dynamic as well. Hence, creating alert for each metric name would be challenging. Is there any different solution to monitor SQS queues?

I configured cloudwatch event rule, to direct all SQS events to cloudwatch log group. But no logs are recorded in log group. Can someone help me out with a solution to monitor these queues.

Comment: How would you like to "monitor" these queues? That is, what metrics are of interest, and what type of Alarms would you want to create? Please edit your question to add details rather than responding via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to read the SQS information and then use it as a variable to create cloudwatch alarms via terraform.

see:

- [AWS CLI SQS List Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/list-queues.html)
- [Terraform alarm resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_metric_alarm)
- [Terraform apply variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#var-39-foo-bar-39-)